# /CLR Option Ignored for Mixed Assembly

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm creating a mixed mode C++ assembly. The assembly contains pointers to C++ unmanaged types and all the classes are C++/CLI types.

I have the option /clr on. However, whenever I build the DLL I get the warning:

```
warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/clr'; ignored
```

This warning doesn't make sense to me as if I turned the /clr off it obviously could not be compiled as native c++ code. So how can the /clr option be unrecognized and ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/clr` is a compiler flag, not a linker flag. (The fact that you're getting a `LNK????` error indicates that you're attempting to pass this flag to the linker.)

Comment: I've only changed the settings as per @Juba's comment. So I'm not sure why it is getting passed to the linker?

Comment: @Seth : Me either. Maybe post the contents of your project file here so we can look at it. (It's just XML, format it as code.)

Comment: Found /clr as an additional option in the linker. Honestly don't know how it got there. I've removed it in the .vcproj file and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from inside Visual Studio then all you have to do is right click on the project and Configuration Properties -> General. Then on the right hand side under Project Details set "Common Language Runtime support" to "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)". This will create a mixed mode C++ project.

This will not add the /clr flag to the linker.